# Why is it not allowed to cast Derived T::* to Base T::*?

Tags: c++, member-pointers, pointer-conversion

**Background:** Many functional languages support algebraic data types, which can to a degree be emulated with virtual functions and inheritance.

The most obvious solution involves a heap allocation, since the derived types come in 
different sizes. However, we should be able to use a union to hold even the largest type on the stack without any extra allocation. This requires an additional pointer-to-base to be stored along with the union, and at the same time complicates copying and assignment.

It's compelling to solve the latter issue by storing a member selector as an offset from the start of the union that points to the active union member. C++ has member pointers which seem almost fit for the purpose, except that the pointer to each member will have a different type.

**Question:** Why is it not allowed to cast Derived T::* to Base T::*?

Here's a toy example, unrelated to the above, that bumps into the same limitation:

```
struct fish {};
struct shark : public fish {};
struct trout : public fish {};

struct aquarium
{
    shark shark;
    trout trout;
};

fish aquarium::* pick_dinner(bool dangerous = true)
{
    if (dangerous)
    {
        return &aquarium::shark;
    }
    return &aquarium::trout;
}

#include <iostream>

void cook(fish&)
{
    std::cerr << "Do it yourself\n";
}

int main()
{
    aquarium spherical, hexagonal;
    fish aquarium::*ingredient = pick_dinner();
    cook(spherical.*ingredient);
    cook(hexagonal.*ingredient);
}
```

The generated compile error:

```
main.cpp:15:16: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'fish aquarium::*' with an rvalue of type 'shark aquarium::*'
        return &aquarium::shark;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:17:12: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'fish aquarium::*' with an rvalue of type 'trout aquarium::*'
    return &aquarium::trout;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: You might try explicit conversion of `&aquarium::shark` and `&aquarium::trout` to `fish *`, then the second and third argument of `?:` will be same type.

Comment: Did you try `if(dangerous) return &aquarium::shark; else return &aquarium::trout` ?

Comment: The whole purpose of using a member pointer is to not refer to a specific instance. This becomes important, in particular, when implementing the copy and assignment constructors for the union+selector combination.

Comment: As for your second commend, CiaPan, that would not make any difference.

Comment: I don't get why you don't just return a `Fish*` from `pick_dinner()` and make `ingredient` a `Fish*`.

Comment: @Galik: because there is no instance to point to.

Comment: It's not a very good test case because it also fails with ordinary pointers: http://ideone.com/HTTOQf

Comment: @Oktalist Oops, you are correct. I fixed the code in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Why is it not allowed to cast `Derived T::*` to `Base T::*`?*

Because it's not allowed by the language standard. The only pointer to member conversion which is allowed, except null member pointer conversion, is the conversion of type `cv T Base::*` to `cv T Derived::*`, as stated by Standard part `4.11/2`.

I don't know the exact the reason for it, but corresponding [Core language issue 794](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_closed.html#794) was [rejected](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3086.html#CH1) due to "no consensus to make this change at this point in the standardization process". [Recent activity](http://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#94) on this issue indicates that it may change in the next C++ standard (C++17).